# Vue and firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2, vue-component

```
 <template lang="html">

  <div class="">
   <ul>


    <li>{{ this.anArray.model }}</li>

   </ul>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import db from '../firebase/init.js';

var link = db.ref('cars').child('-KoKST99e110OZs6g111');
var thedata = link.once('value').then(function(snapshot){return snapshot.val()});

export default {
  name: 'view',
  firebase: {
       anArray:thedata
    }
}
</script>
```

I trying to get the object inside that path on firebase database but is answer unknown.  the connection is good, the problem is how Im doing it. Help!

Comment: Your code is throwing away the key when it set the snapshot's value to `anArray`. To get the key of the snapshot, use `snapshot.key`.

Comment: Thank you frank I mean the object inside that address.